# Merging dataframes from two dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have dict1  and dict2

```
dict1={"a":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"],data=[[2,3],[2,3]]),"b":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"],data=[[12,3],[45,9]])}


dict2={"a":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"],data=[[2,3],[2,3]]),"b":pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2"],data=[[12,3],[45,9]])}
```

Both dictionaries' values are dataframes. The two dictionaries have full key match. 
I want to merge the dataframes which share the same key on column "col1".

Comment: what is your expect output ?

Comment: Are the dictonaries required for the program? Merging would be way easier if you use the dataframes. Something along the lines of `newdf = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['id'])`

Comment: `pd.concat(dict1.values(),keys=dict1.keys()).merge(
    pd.concat(dict2.values(),keys=dict2.keys()),on='col1',left_index=True,right_index=True)` ?

Comment: Initially I thought I would expect the result in a dictionary again but now when I think after the comments dataframe may suffice. I expect dataframes for key "a" to be merged , dataframes for key "b" to be merged. 
@anky_91 - thanks for the suggestion; yet the provided code results in a merged frame only for key "a"

Comment: you should post the expected df

Comment: @MartinYordanovGeorgiev just filter `dict1['a']` and `dict2['a']` then merge on col1?